# How do you call a method of a generic type in java?

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to make a method which takes in a variable object type as a parameter, and then updates a database depending on what object was passed, a bit like how Petapoco works for C#. For this I am trying to use a generic method in which the object that is passed passes a number of checks before it is inserted/updated into its relevant table. A number of questions on Stack Overflow point me towards using a method signature like this:

```
public <T> void upsertObject(Class<T> objectClass, T actualObject) { }
```

Within the method I would like to be able to call methods like `actualObject.getId()` but the compiler needs to know the actual type of the object to call its relevant methods. Is there any way around this? How would I go about achieving these calls?

EDIT:

Edited for more clarity

After adding an interface with which to bind T, I found I was getting the error:

"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getId() from the type CycleComponent"

The method now looks like this, the error line is under T.getId()

```
public <T extends CycleComponent> void upsertObject(Class<T> objectClass, T fitProObject) {
    if (objectClass.getName() == "Cycle") {
        if (isInserted(T.getId(), "Cycles")) {
            // update the database
        }else {
            // insert into the database
        }
    }

}
```

The interface looks like:

```
public interface CycleComponent {

    String getId();

}
```

And the method in the Cycle class looks like:

```
public String getId() {
    return this.cycleId;
}
```

Comment: Do you expect your `actualObject` to be of a type that implements `getId()`? In that case you need to make `T` bounded to the interface or the class that declares `getId()`

Comment: By using interfaces/superclasses, reflection, annotations, or so on. But writing a custom db framework is a lot of work, so I hope you realize that you will be producing hobby code and not a production grade framework, right?

Comment: try adding check if object is instance of that class

Comment: You can only call `upsertObject` with a class literal (e.g. `SomeClass.class`) as the first parameter (or, of course, some parameter passed to the calling method, which is itself a class literal). If you can avoid having to pass `objectClass`, it would be much better.

Comment: @ernest_k yes, getId() is a method of all the classes which are possibly passed to this generic method.

Comment: @MichaelTracey `T.getId()` is wrong. It should be `fitProObject.getId()` (since `fitProObject` is a variable of type `T`). In addition, don't compare `String`s with `==`, use `equals`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with generic type bounds.

Define:

```
public <T extends SomeType> void upsertObject(Class<T> objectClass, T actualObject) { }
```

Where `SomeType` is a class or interface, and you'll be able to call methods of `SomeType` on the `actualObject` instance.

This would limit this method to being used only with types that extend `SomeType` (if it's a class) or implement `SomeType` (if it's an interface).

For example:

```
public interface SomeType {
    String getId();
}
```

And:

```
public <T extends SomeType> void upsertObject(Class<T> objectClass, T actualObject) {
    if (actualObject.getId() != null) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have created a new interface and implemented it in the relevant classes, but now I get the error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getId()  ?

Comment: @MichaelTracey can you show the code? It sounds like you are trying to call an instance method (`getId()`) without an instance on which to call it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this doesn't have to be absolutely generic (for example, it probably doesn't make sense to upsert a `java.lang.Integer`, right?), I'd define an interface with all the methods you need, and add that to the generic classification:

```
public interface Upsertable {
    int getID();

    // Other methods you may need...
}

public <T extends Upsertable> void upsertObject(Class<T> objectClass, T actualObject) { }
```